# PHP, HTML creating dynamic table with inner table

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, html-table

Suppose I should create a table dynamically inside a loop.

```
<tr level="p">
  <td colspan="12" level="pdt">
    <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead level="pdt">
          <tr>
             <th colspan="2">Test Questions</th>
             <th colspan="2">Question Answers</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody level="pdt" id="first_inner_table_body">
          <tr>
             @if('some condition check'))
               <td colspan="2" column_excel="B">
                 <table class="table table-hover">
                   <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th>Question Text [En]</th>
                        <th>Question Text [Dari]</th>
                        <th>Question Text [Pashto]</th>
                        <th>Question Type </th>
                     </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                      @foreach($value['participant_test_questions']['id'] as $question_keys=>$question_value)
                        <tr>
                          <td column_excel="B">{!! $value['participant_test_questions']['test_question_text_en'][$question_keys] !!}</td>
                          <td column_excel="B">{!! $value['participant_test_questions']['test_question_text_pr'][$question_keys] !!}</td>
                          <td column_excel="B">{!! $value['participant_test_questions']['test_question_text_pa'][$question_keys] !!}</td>
                          <td column_excel="B">{{ ($value['participant_test_questions']['test_question_type'][$question_keys] == '1' ? trans('wld_titles.descriptive_question') : ($value['participant_test_questions']['test_question_type'][$question_keys] == '2' ? trans('wld_titles.single_selective_question') : ($value['participant_test_questions']['test_question_type'][$question_keys] == '3' ? trans('wld_titles.multi_selective_question') : 'Unknown')))}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      @endforeach
                   </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2" column_excel="B">
                 <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>Answer Text [En]</th>
                          <th>Answer Text [Dari]</th>
                          <th>Answer Text [Pashto]</th>
                          <th>Question Type </th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    @if($item['status'][$test_map_key] != '0' AND $childDocResult != '')
                       @foreach($childDocResult['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'] AS $child_row)
                           @foreach($child_row as $data_row)  
                              <tr>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td></td>
                              </tr>
                           @endforeach

                      @endforeach
                  @endif                                        
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>

      @endif
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The main structure that i want to create is inside a `tr->td` i should create a nested `table` with to column header 'th', one of them is `Test Questions` and the next one is `Question Answers`, now for each header I have separate inner table, one table for questions and the next one for question answers.
I have two separate array for question and answer, but has relation between them. for example one question may have 1 or more than one answer.
Now suppose question array has 4 bundle of question and each bundle has 5 question, so the first loop will iterate 4 time, and in each iteration i show write 5 question. after the iteration if finished i should iterate through answer arrays and write the relevant answers of each question.
The problem arise when i want to create the inner table of answers.
the following pictures shows the problem.
[image: table view]
[image: table]

Comment: @MS.Nehal It is a blade template used with laravel, instead of php tags I have use from `@` blade syntax.

Comment: it's not clear to me what the problem is. were you expecting the answers table to be populated with data? there are no blade template tags inside the `<td></td>` of the answers table so it is normal that those rows are empty